# Repetition Task C# Server side

Tags: c#, asp.net, cron, scheduled-tasks

Net Web Form app that gather user information and depend on their performance should send them email every night. 
i need to find elegant way to run one class or web form page that do the processing and  depending of the performance will send email. i can do this on Windows form application and have Windows Task Scheduler to run my windows form application, but i would like to know that i can do this on server side, "have one class or web page that will run every day"
i have seen Cron job but this is asp.net application which it is running on windows.
Any Suggestion or tutorial would be very helpful 
Sorry for English "mistake"
Thank you

Comment: So you cant run a windows service on the server? - Run a scheduled task elsewhere that simply calls a URL that triggers the process on the server.

Comment: This is being done on company server that i have full access to, but i want to know if there is any other way "not the scheduled task" that i can make my class to fire every night at some time, if it is possible i can use it in other project that i dont have full access to server

Comment: If your app is a WebForm app, I suggest to have the related webservices together in order to do not maintain separated versions of your system parts. That will avoid you a lot of headaches ensuring your separated apps are in sync with the code base.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recurring tasks library like [Hangfire](http://hangfire.io/) o [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/). These libraries allow you to schedule Fire-and-forget tasks, and they will also provide you with a dashboard page for monitoring.